# getting recall and precision of score function in MultinomialNB in sklearn

Tags: multinomial

I want to get the recall and precision in my prediction but I got confused. This function "score" in MultinomialNB in sklearn has no capability to return a predicted list or a thing that help me to reach the precision and recall.For example:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
model.score(x_test, y_test)
```

Here I have a model that is going to predict but MultinomialNB() has no function to provid the precision or recall or a predicted list ets.